# Send multiple objects which contains files to WCF Service using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I've been scratching my head for quite a few days now.

I am trying to send a Javascript object to a WCF Service.
My objective is to have a object with some properties (where one should be the file or its bytes) which I can send to the service.

So far my javascript looks like this where I do the population and the call to the service:

```
            var data = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                //data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                var obj = {};
                obj.Name = files[i].name;
                obj.File = files[i];
                obj.Dir = "testDir";

                data.append(obj.Name, obj);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "WCFService.svc/Upload",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    //Do something on success
                }
            });
```

This is the service. It is not doing anything real yet, but once I can figure out how to upload the files using objects I will continue with the service's code.

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void Upload(object obj)
        {
            string qwe = "";
        }
```

At the moment, the service is being called, but no data is contained. the Obj is null once it reaches the Service.

Any help appreciated!